# Move comments to new column in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one column in a table where (almost) each cell in that column has a comment (red triangle), I would like to move all the comments into a new column.

#### Example of what I have:

> **Col.1**
>   MIT (comment: MA)
>   Harvard (comment: MA)
>   Yale (comment: CT)
>   NYU (no comment)

#### What I would like to have:

> **Col.1, Col.2**
>   MIT, MA
>   Harvard, MA
>   Yale, CT
>   NYU, ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is possible only with VBA. Try the ff. user-defined function:

```
Public Function GetComment(c As Range) As String
    If c.Comment Is Nothing Then
        GetComment = "?"
    Else
        GetComment = Replace(c.Comment.Text, c.Comment.Author & ":", "")
    End If
End Function
```

**To create the UDF**:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.
2. Paste the code above.
3. Close the VBA editor.

*Note:

If you'd like to show the comment author's name as well, replace the 5th line with:

`GetComment = c.Comment.Text`*

**To use the function**, enter the ff. into a cell in the column where you want to place the comments and then copy it down.

```
=GetComment(B1)
```

Where:
`B1` is a cell that contains the comment you want to get

Here's an example of how to use it:

[image]